# 403 error when listing the members of an audience

Tags: 2007, error, audience-targeting

The following code runs fine as an administrator but crashes with a 403 forbidden error when run as a non-admin on the `am.GetAudience("My Audience")` call. Can anyone spot why, I'm running with elevated privileges?

```
List<string> accounts = new List<string>();
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysite"))
    {
        AudienceManager am = new AudienceManager(ServerContext.GetContext(site));
        foreach (UserInfo member in am.GetAudience("My Audience").GetMembership())
        {
            accounts.Add(member.NTName.ToLower());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: bizarrly, using `Audience a = am["My Audience"]` works without elevating privileges....

Comment: I guess you mean `am.Audiences["My Audience"]`? This is because GetAudience calls an internal method CanAccess() that checks for UserProfileApplicationAdminRights and throws an UnauthorizedAccessException if you are not allowed to manage audiences. If you use the Audiences collection index remember to place the code inside a `try/catch` and catch the `AudienceArgumentException` to avoid the code to break if an audience does not exist. You see similar behaviour on User Profile Manager

Answer (score 1):

Not that I have actually tried this, but I suspect the problem could be because the call to elevate priveliges only elevates up to the web application pool service account - this account may not have permission to access your SSP (which is where the audiences are managed).